# LimeJS Projects Show Blank Screen

Tags: limejs

I recently followed a Youtube tutorial on getting LimeJS setup and I'm having trouble getting any of my projects to show up in Chrome. Although I'm new to programming I followed the instructions to the "t" (LimeJS Tutorials | Installing on Windows). Below are the test logs and paths to svn/python/limejs. I also added all paths in the PATH systems variable and I have been running everything through cmd prompt. Thanks in advance for your help!

Subversion: C:\Users\Master Blaster\Documents\Subversion

Python: C:\Python34

LimeJS: C:\limejs

Lime Unit Tests - lime.director [FAILED]
/C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm
6 of 6 tests run in 12ms.
1 passed, 5 failed.
2 ms/test. 49 files loaded.
.
11:24:14.934  Start
11:24:14.935  testBounds : PASSED
11:24:14.935  testCoordinateConversion : FAILED (run individually)
11:24:14.939  ERROR in testCoordinateConversion
lime is not defined

> (unknown)
>   testCoordinateConversion at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm:88:20
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:14.940  testDirectorInit : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:24:14.941  ERROR in testDirectorInit
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testDirectorInit at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm:48:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:14.941  testHitTest : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:24:14.942  ERROR in testHitTest
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testHitTest at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm:104:20
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:14.942  testPartialSizes : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:24:14.942  ERROR in testPartialSizes
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testPartialSizes at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm:69:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:14.943  testPausing : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:24:14.946  ERROR in testPausing
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testPausing at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/director.htm:109:20
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:14.946  Done

Lime Unit Tests - lime.dirty [FAILED]
/C:/limejs/lime/tests/dirty.htm
1 of 1 tests run in 4ms.
0 passed, 1 failed.
4 ms/test. 50 files loaded.
.
11:24:43.142  Start
11:24:43.143  testDirtyQueue : FAILED (run individually)
11:24:43.145  ERROR in testDirtyQueue
lime is not defined

> (unknown)
>   testDirtyQueue at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/dirty.htm:52:15
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:24:43.146  Done

Lime Unit Tests - lime.scene [FAILED]
/C:/limejs/lime/tests/scene.htm
3 of 3 tests run in 7ms.
0 passed, 3 failed.
2 ms/test. 49 files loaded.
.
11:25:00.258  Start
11:25:00.259  testSceneActivation : FAILED (run individually)
11:25:00.262  ERROR in testSceneActivation
lime is not defined

> (unknown)
>   setUp at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/scene.htm:45:17
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:835:14
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:00.262  testSceneInit : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:00.264  ERROR in testSceneInit
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   setUp at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/scene.htm:45:17
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:835:14
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:00.264  testScenePushPop : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:00.264  ERROR in testScenePushPop
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   setUp at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/scene.htm:45:17
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:835:14
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:00.265  Done

Lime Unit Tests - lime.director [FAILED]
/C:/limejs/lime/tests/schedulemanager.htm
3 of 3 tests run in 7ms.
0 passed, 3 failed.
2 ms/test. 50 files loaded.
.
11:25:13.861  Start
11:25:13.862  testCallAfter : FAILED (run individually)
11:25:13.865  ERROR in testCallAfter
lime is not defined

> (unknown)
>   testCallAfter at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/schedulemanager.htm:82:5
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:13.865  testScheduleWithDelay : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:13.866  ERROR in testScheduleWithDelay
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testScheduleWithDelay at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/schedulemanager.htm:106:5
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:13.867  testScheduler : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:13.867  ERROR in testScheduler
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testScheduler at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/schedulemanager.htm:48:4
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:13.867  Done

Lime Unit Tests - lime.style [FAILED]
/C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm
6 of 6 tests run in 9ms.
0 passed, 6 failed.
2 ms/test. 49 files loaded.
.
11:25:27.234  Start
11:25:27.235  testBorderRadius : FAILED (run individually)
11:25:27.238  ERROR in testBorderRadius
lime is not defined

> (unknown)
>   testBorderRadius at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:59:21
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.238  testCommonProperties : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:27.239  ERROR in testCommonProperties
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testCommonProperties at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:50:45
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.239  testSetSize : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:27.240  ERROR in testSetSize
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testSetSize at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:176:5
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.240  testTransform : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:27.241  ERROR in testTransform
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testTransform at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:107:21
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.242  testTransformOrigin : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:27.242  ERROR in testTransformOrigin
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testTransformOrigin at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:96:21
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.242  testTransitions : FAILED (run individually)
>   11:25:27.243  ERROR in testTransitions
>   lime is not defined
>   (unknown)
>   testTransitions at file:///C:/limejs/lime/tests/style.htm:138:9
>   goog.testing.TestCase.Test.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:1076:12
>   goog.testing.TestCase.cycleTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:836:18
>   goog.testing.TestCase.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:420:8
>   goog.testing.TestCase.runTests at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testcase.js:597:8
>   goog.testing.TestRunner.execute at file:///C:/limejs/closure/closure/goog/testing/testrunner.js:267:17
>   11:25:27.243  Done

Answer (score 1):

To anyone with the same issue I found a post with the solution. Turns out Python 3.X is the culprit, uninstall Python 3.X and install Python 2.7. Make sure to test a newly created project using Python 2.7, any previous projects created using Python 3.X will still not work.

[limejs int step installation issue with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350458/limejs-int-step-installation-issue-with-closure)